# Problems stretching an image in a TD Tag

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that seems to only occurs in IE (i'm currently using IE8). Basically, i have web pages that consist of a header, content area and a footer. I am trying to stretch an image to be displayed as a left and right border in the content area. the image is not a solid color, so simply setting a border property would not work. In all browsers but IE, the image stretches just fine.

The site is heavily table based due to the fact that it is written for a CMS known as NetSuite. A lot of the tables and html are created by the CMS and are very difficult and tricky to modify.

You can see the page in action at - [web site page](http://staging.marware.com/iphone-cases/iphone-4-cases)

I have tried numerous combinations of height:100% and different positioning values with little help. One of the problems is that the height of the content area is dynamically set.

The code in place now looks like this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1020" height="100%" align="center">
<tr style="height:100%;">

    <!-- left side image -->
    <td style="width:9px; height:100%;"><img src="http://www.marware.com/images/body_outer_border.png" border="0" height="100%" width="9" /></td>
    <td valign="top" width="400" align="center">
    <!-- right side image -->
    <td style="width:9px; height:100%;"><img src="http://www.marware.com/images/body_outer_border.png" border="0" height="100%" width="9" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: How on earth is that page **327KB** and **over 7000 lines**? :S

Answer (score 1):

```
<td style="height:100%; position:relative;">
    <img style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" border=0 src="http://www.marware.com/images/body_outer_border.png" width="9" height="100%">
</td>
```

Make the `img` absoultely positioned at `0,0` with 100% width and height. And relative positioning on the `td` so the absolute positioning is relative to it. I'm relatively sure that this absolutely works in IE8.

Comment: It absolutely does not work in IE6-7, but as a workaround you could add `class="border-side"` to the `td`:s and `<!--[if lte IE 7]><style>.border-side{filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2C78BA', endColorstr='#E8F0F8',GradientType=0 );} .border-side img{display:none;}</style><![endif]-->` to `head`